# Spring batch - read and write to database using chunks and multi thread using taskexecutor

Tags: java, multithreading, jdbc, spring-batch, batch-processing

my code able to read and write to database but only one chunk after that this process stops. fail to execute other chunks.

here is the error looks like
**org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: Unexpected cursor position change.**

Step Implementation

```
@Bean
    public Step step(StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory) throws Exception {
       ThreadPoolTaskExceutor taskExcutorInstance = new ThreadPoolTaskExceutor();
       taskExcutorInstance.setCorePoolSize(10);
       taskExcutorInstance.setMaxPoolSize(10);

       return stepBuilderFactory
                .get("read from DB and Write to DB")
                .<Object, Object>chunk(1000)
                .reader(reader(null))
                .writer(writer())
                .taskExecutor(taskExcutorInstance)
                .build();
    }
```

for reader im using JdbcCursorItemReader and for writer im using JdbcbatchItemWriter.
I'm trying to read and write multiple chuncks at the same time

if I need to disable verifyCursorPosition how exactly we need disable this ?

Answer (score 3):

The `JdbcCursorItemReader` extends `AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader` which is [NOT thread-safe](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/4.3.x/api/org/springframework/batch/item/support/AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.html). You can try to synchronize its `read` operation (by decorating it with a [`SynchronizedItemStreamReader`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/4.3.x/api/org/springframework/batch/item/support/SynchronizedItemStreamReader.html)), otherwise you need to use a thread-safe reader like the `JdbcPagingItemReader`.